# AngularJS REST async call not returning data

Tags: rest, angularjs, angular-services

I am new to angular, in an application I am writing angular services for doing REST API call.

What I am doing like below:

```
    App.service('dataService', function(){
    this.getNewsAndTweets = function(){
        var newsCall = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/news/'
        });

        var tweetsCall = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/tweets/'
        });
        $q.all(newsCall, tweetsCall).then(function(values) {
            var news = values[0].data.results;
            var tweets = values[1].data.results;
            var a = doSomeThing(news);
            var b = doSomeThingToo(tweets);
            return [a, b];  
            });

        }
}
```

As `$q.all(newsCall, tweetsCall).then` is an asynchronous call, I am getting null array in news when I am calling my service.

Inside my controller I am calling it like `dataService.getNewsAndTweets()` and getting null array, as far as my understanding as $q is an async call which is returning data later.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return the promise in your service

```
return $q.all(newsCall, tweetsCall).then(function(values) {
        var news = values[0].data.results;
        var tweets = values[1].data.results;
        var a = doSomeThing(news);
        var b = doSomeThingToo(tweets);
        return [a, b];  
        });
```

en then in your controller wait for it to resolve:

```
dataService.getNewsAndTweets().then(function(data){
    $scope.news = data[0];
    $scope.tweets = data[0];
});
```